# How to reshape data into wide format?

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data set like this:

```
structure(list(var1 = c("APE", "APE", "APE", "APE", "APE", "APE", "GIT",
"APE", "APE", "APE", "APE", "APE", "APE", "APE", "GIT"), var2 = c("AVVAL",
"AULASU", "APALA", "AEA", "ATUPVA", "ASATAP", "ADLO", "AKOKU", "AVVAL",
"AULASU", "APALA", "AEA", "ATUPVA", "ASATAP", "ADLO"), var3 = c(NA,
NA, 1L, 101L, 17122009L, 1L, NA, 684L, NA, NA, 1L, 10L, 17122L,
1L, NA)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), row.names = c(NA,
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I reshape this data into wide format? I tried this

```
reshape(h, idvar="var2", v.names="var3", timevar="var1", direction="wide")
```

but it is not giving me a correct results. The correct result is:

```
  var1 ADLO AEA AKOKU APALA ASATAP   ATUPVA AULASU AVVAL
1  APE  NaN 101   NA      1      1 17122009     NA    NA
2  APE  NaN  10   684     1      1    17122     NA    NA
3  GIT   NA NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN
4  GIT   NA NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edited

The only way I can get to your expected results is to add a new column to the data.frame.  It seems to me that there is some information implicit about your data that isn't contained in the data.  In other words, there must be some kind of grouping variable that identifies certain records as belonging together.

Since I can't double-guess what this information is, in my answer I am going to assume that each occurrence of `GIT` marks the end of a record:

```
x <- grep("GIT", h$var1)
h$rec <- rep(seq_along(x), times=c(x[1], diff(x)))

library(reshape2)
mh <- melt(h, measure.vars="var3")
cast(mh, rec+var1~var2, id.var="rec", measure.var="value", fun.aggregate=mean)

  rec var1 ADLO AEA AKOKU APALA ASATAP   ATUPVA AULASU AVVAL
1   1  APE  NaN  10   NaN     1      1 17122009     NA    NA
2   1  GIT   NA NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN
3   2  APE  NaN  10   684     1      1 17122009     NA    NA
4   2  GIT   NA NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN   Na
```

---

### Original answer

I find the package `reshape2` much easier to comprehend than the built-in `reshape` function. This package provides two functions:

- `melt` to make a wide `data.frame` tall
- `cast` to make a tall `data.frame` wide

In your case you need `cast`:

```
library(reshape2)
cast(h, var1~var2, value="var3", fun.aggregate=mean)

  var1 ADLO AEA AKOKU APALA ASATAP   ATUPVA AULASU AVVAL
1  APE  NaN  10   684     1      1 17122009     NA    NA
2  GIT   NA NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have also duplicate records, so that APE should have 2 rows. Now this is grouping data based on var1, not reshaping it.

Answer (score 0):

I add a new variable due to the meaning of `GIT`:

```
 dat$id <- cumsum(dat$var1=='GIT')
```

First I do the aggregation:

```
datMean <- aggregate(var3 ~ var2 * id, data=dat, FUN=mean)

> datMean
    var2 id     var3
1    AEA  0      101
2  APALA  0        1
3 ASATAP  0        1
4 ATUPVA  0 17122009
5    AEA  1       10
6  AKOKU  1      684
7  APALA  1        1
8 ASATAP  1        1
9 ATUPVA  1    17122
```

and then the conversion from long to wide:

```
datWide <- reshape(datMean, direction='wide', idvar='id', timevar='var2')

> datWide
  id var3.AEA var3.APALA var3.ASATAP var3.ATUPVA var3.AKOKU
1  0      101          1           1    17122009         NA
5  1       10          1           1       17122        684
```